# Copy file based upon file path in cell to destination file path specified in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a reasonably regular monthly process where I am trying to move files from one folder to another. It is several files in several different source folders to several destination folders. To save myself time I'd like to create a Macro in a third sort of directory file that copies the files based upon the given file path in one cell (we'll call this the "source") to the file path given in some other cell ("destination"). I wanted to start this using just one source file being moved to one destination path, with the idea that I can later duplicate the macro for several of these files. I have put together some code using something similar found here, but it isn't seeming to find either the file or path.

```
Dim rngFile As Range, cel As Range
Dim desPath As String, filename As String

Set rngFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A26")

desPath = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B26") 'change to a valid path

For Each cel In rngFile
    If Dir(cel) <> "" Then
        filename = Dir(cel) 'Returns the filename
        FileCopy cel, desPath & filename 'copy to folder
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the path end with  \ ?

Comment: What are the values of A26 and B26? All of this code is essentially equal to the single line `If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A26"))<> "" Then FileCopy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A26"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B26") & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A26")` I'm not suggesting you change to that, but does that make sense for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make sense for what I am trying to do, and I just noticed that. I probably don't need the if statement at all. Cell A26 contains the file path for the source file, and cell B26 contains the destination file path (pointing to a folder with no file in it at present).